# calling methods from imported files (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working with SpriteKit and need to call a method from MyScene.m within ViewController.m I have the interface set up with the method, and I create a MyScene object in ViewController interface. The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<ViewController 0x9e3d5b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key SwipeLeftRight.'
```

I feel like I must be missing something simple but I don't see it. Please help!

Comment: Your xib contains some invalid connections to IBOutlets

Comment: Use an exception breakpoint to pinpoint where this error occurs.

Comment: @akashg what do you mean by "exception breakpoint"? I put a breakpoint at the beginning of my viewDidLoad method but the exception occurs before this point.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I am using Xcode 5, I am not using xib files

Comment: Then my dear friend you might be using storyboard or there is something else then

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, even then the only thing I have done with storyboard is add gesture recognizers, these are definitely connected correctly, everything else I have done in code.

Comment: Then what is `SwipeLeftRight`? it looks like a gesture to me

Comment: Exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @akashg, adding the breakpoint did nothing, at least that I can understand, it seems to happen before my code is even executed... how?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore like I said a few gestures is the only thing I've done I am positive these are connected correctly.

Comment: If nothing works just disconnect all the outlets and then run the code, just to check if this problem is related to storyboard or not.

Comment: Sow method definition, implementation and invocation please

Comment: @InderKumarRathore was correct it was an outlet issue, I have no idea where they came from, and they weren't in my interface.

Comment: @JDOdle I want to kill you for that >.< , I hope you learned something..